# Is there any way to show pre-selected items in the react-admin's ReferenceArrayInput -> SelectArrayInput component?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have the following code in a `react-admin` edit form:

```
<Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
       <ReferenceArrayInput
          source="clients"
          reference="client"
          required={true}
          validate={[required()]}
        >
            <SelectArrayInput optionText={ClientOptionRenderer} />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

When clicked the ReferenceArrayInput -> SelectArrayInput component on the ui, it does show all the record-related items (coming from `client` RestFul API) and it allows their multiple selection.

However, when the form loads in the first place, it does not show pre-selected items (although they are held in the form state, if any). Is there any particular property in the React-Admin SelectArrayInput component to set so it shows pre-selected items by default?

Comment: No it should display them once they have been fetched. Can you setup a codesandbox showing the issue ?

Comment: Hello,

1) Form screenshot and data returned by server, see the drop down menus  label i.e. 'Roles * *' in small text size and if I open the Roles drop-down the list is there but no item is selected although the `Cole Goyette` client is fetched from server:

[![https://imgur.com/WO92PCf.png](https://imgur.com/WO92PCf.png)](https://imgur.com/WO92PCf.png)

2) I've got some utility buttons to reset the roles/client array and when I do it with roles the UI actually changes and turns red:

[![https://imgur.com/ltQHTp5.png](https://imgur.com/ltQHTp5.png)](https://imgur.com/ltQHTp5.png)

Comment: Basically it seems the SelectArrayInput components are aware the data is there, but they not display it initially, and when I reset the `clients` or `roles` properties via the utility buttons, then the UI components change (and form validates correctly stopping its submission).

Comment: Please open an issue on our repository with a link to codesandbox showing the problem